# Comparing dates and filling a new column based on this condition

Tags: python, database, pandas

I want to check if one date is between two other dates (everything in the same row). If this is true I want that a new colum is filled with a sales value of the same table. If not the row shall be dropped.

The code shall iterate over the entire dataframe.

This is my code:

```
for row in final:
x = 0
if pd.to_datetime(final['start_date'].iloc[x]) < pd.to_datetime(final['purchase_date'].iloc[x]) < pd.to_datetime(final['end_date'].iloc[x]):
    final['new_col'].iloc[x] = final['sales'].iloc[x]
else:
    final.drop(final.iloc[x])
x = x + 1
print(final['new_col'])
```

Instead of the values of `final[sales]` I just get `0` back.
Does anyone know where the mistake is or any other efficient way to tackle this?

The DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you include a sample of your original dataframe?

Comment: If you need a more efficient way you should considerate not iterating. Or is it a must to iterate ?

Comment: @rahlf23 just added a picture of the data. "verkauf_woche_1" is the sales_date.

Comment: @AntonioManrique how do I considerate ?

Comment: Could you please correct your indentation? Currently you have posted invalid Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this:

First, creating the new column:

```
import numpy as np
final['new_col'] = np.where(pd.to_datetime(final['start_date'])<(pd.to_datetime(final['purchase_date']), final['sales'], np.NaN)
```

Then, you just drop the Na's:

```
final.dropna(inplace=True)
```